# The way how run program from shell script and specify its positon on screen

Tags: macos, shell, unix

is in shell (Mac OS X Lion) a way how run program on specify position on screen?
I want to run two programs and specify their position on screen so one window will be next to another and they will be centered on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to hack something together using AppleScript. [This link](http://www.ithug.com/2007/09/applescript-moving-and-resizing-windows/) shows you how to set the window geometry of a certain application. The problem might be in actually talking to the processes that you just started. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292962/problem-passing-parameter-to-applescript-via-terminal-bashscript) deals a bit with using the process id to talk to an app using AppleScript.