# How to make Automator run Shell Script that requires sudo password?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, automator

I used this script below to change mac address randomly every time it is ran.

```
openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//' | xargs sudo ifconfig en0 ether

ifconfig en0 | grep ether
```

I want Automator to do it for me. When I run this Shell Script, it runs successfully but when I actually open Terminal and run

```
ifconfig en0 | grep ether
```

to see if it changed MAC address I find out it didn't.

If i manually enter such script into Terminal, it works perfectly. 
What should I do?

Comment: I just found out this answer that solves it in more "developer friendly" way. Beware that it runs all commands as root. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941026/1310733

Answer (score 4):

Try creating an `AppleScript` instead:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    do shell script "openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\\(..\\)/\\1:/g; s/.$//' | xargs sudo ifconfig en0 ether" with administrator privileges
    do shell script "ifconfig en0 | grep ether"
    return input
end run
```

It should ask you to enter your adminstrator password, then change the mac address. Automater is better suited to run Applescripts generally, as shell scripts can sometimes be problematic.

Comment: Note that if it needs to be in the form of an Automator workflow, you can use the "Run Applescript" action to include this in the workflow. It's a bit indirect (using Automator to run an AppleScript which runs a shell script), but it's the easiest way I've found to run commands as root from Automator.

Comment: does this still work? I'm getting permission denied when doing this

Comment: @spracketchip: Yes, it worked fine for me just now when I tried (macOS 10.13.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can place them directly in your `root` directory. You will need to have root privileges to access the function but it will not require pass phrase input.